# Want to use `diffenv` but have different wave lengths

Tags: r, audio

I'm trying to use `diffenv` to see the surface difference between two audio files.

Below are the codes adopted, but I'm faced with the error:

> Error in diffenv(a1, a2, f = f, plot = TRUE, main = "surface
>   difference between ’a’ and ’b’") : wave1 and wave2 should have the
>   same length

```
f<-16000    
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3),byrow=TRUE,nc=2))    
env(a1,f=f,colwave="red",title="sound ’a’")    
env(a2,f=f,colwave="blue",title="sound ’b’")    
diffenv(a1,a2,f=f,plot=TRUE, main="surface difference between ’a’ and ’b’")
```

Is there a way I can amend the wave length so that they are comparable? Or is this not advisable?

Answer (score 0):

You could zero pad the shorter file to the length of the larger.

If it is advisable or not depends on what you will do with the data! If you are using this as a distance estimation between the two envelopes, it sort of makes sense. There are also scenarios where it would be beneficial to ignore the trailing end of diffenvs output.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input. Do you know how I can amend the wave length in R?